# do a hide on two jquery variables at once (basic question)

Tags: jquery

i cant seem to get this right and would like to know the exact syntax to use.

say i have two variables defined in jQuery

```
var cat = $('#cat');
var dog = $('#dog');
```

i want for example... hide both divs.

i know without the vars it would be `$('#cat, #dog').hide();`
no matter how i do it with the variables i cant get it to work.

```
(cat,dog).hide();
```

thanks!

Comment: do that separately, or store both in one variable.

Comment: as @aditya has pointed out, the answer to this question "could" depend on how many farm animals you're trying to add. It could start looking pretty ugly if you have to add 20 or 50 elements. @Harman's answer is great and efficient, but will begin to look awful if you're adding a huge number of elements. @aditya's answer will work to iterate over a large number of elements.

Comment: Lol @rockinthesixstring farm animals just laughing. Nice to know jquery will perform that sequential, but its going to hapen simultaneosly even if the command is run sequentially.

Answer (score 13):

```
cat.add(dog).hide()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to add elements to an existing selector:

```
var dog = $('#dog'),
    cat = $('#cat');
dog.add(cat).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
var $1 = $("#cat"), $2 = $("#dog");
$.each([$1, $2], function(t){ $(this).hide()} )
```

This scales to as many DIVs as you might need.

Comment: This is basically the same as: `$1.hide(); $2.hide()`, but *actually* the same happens in the jQuery source. Iterating over each item and applying `.hide()`;

Comment: Yes, but it's easier to scale for more DIVs. What the OP is trying to do is in-efficient either way; I don't think an in-efficient question can have an efficient answer.

Comment: trying to make this work so far none of the answers actually work. @aditya, why is the question inefficient? i need to hide and show selects based on the selected item. it was working fine with it all spelled out. then i tried to be more efficient by adding in variables and now it doesnt work. am i doing something inherently the wrong way??

Comment: @liz - I added a jsfiddle link on @Harmen's answer that works.

Comment: @liz Your question is extremely vague. Optimization isn't a general thing --- one optimizes code for specific situations. Without knowing what you're actually trying to do, we can't give you good code to solve your problem. For all we know, your problem is a semantic one, not syntactic.

Comment: nope not semantic problem, it all works fine when i spell out each one without a variable for it. i tried your fiddle. doesnt work for me.

Comment: @liz That's the question then, isn't it? Why are you trying to make a variable for each one?